# Help with If Statement in JavaScript Button

Tags: javascript, button

So I have a button on a Custom Object that simply updates a checkbox field. I am trying to add an if statement to this button so that if the checkbox was already checked when the button was clicked it displays a window stating it was already selected and cannot be selected again. Below is what I have so far. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/apex.js")} 
var bo = new sforce.SObject("Buyer__c");
if(bo.Put_Trucks_on_48_Hour_Hold__c = 'True')
{
alert('Error : This Buyers Order has already been placed within a 48 Hour Hold and cannot be placed within one again.');
}
else{
bo.Id = '{!Buyer__c.Id }';
bo.Put_Trucks_on_48_Hour_Hold__c = 'True';
var result = sforce.connection.update([bo]);
if(result[0].getBoolean("success"))
{
window.location.reload();
}
else{
alert('Error : '+result);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you're having? Also, I'll assume it's a typo (but maybe not), in your `if` statement you're using `=` which is not a comparison operator. You should be using `==` or `===`.

Comment: Are you doing this logic in a custom button on a standard page?

Comment: Your request seems a bit odd to me as worded (from a user experience standpoint). Do you intend for there to be no way to cancel a 48 hour hold once a hold has been placed? If clicking the checkbox once indicates that a hold should be placed, I'd expect that clicking it again would remove the hold (rather than attempting to place the hold again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a few problems.

- `bo` is simply a record "in memory" and has no relation to anything in the database. Your alert will never happen because you haven't loaded the data.
- `=` is assignment, not comparison. Use `==` for comparison.
- `True` or `'True'` will never match. In JavaScript, it is always just `true`.
- Don't compare a Boolean to true or false. It's already true or false.
- The apex library is only needed for the likes of sforce.apex.execute or sforce.apex.executeAnonymous. You don't need it here.

The code you're looking for would be more like this:

```
{!RequireScript("/soap/ajax/38.0/connection.js")}
if({!Buyer__c.Put_Trucks_on_48_Hour_Hold__c}) {
    alert('Error : This Buyers Order has already been placed within a 48 Hour Hold and cannot be placed within one again.');
} else {
    var bo = new sforce.SObject('Buyer__c');
    bo.Id = '{!Buyer__c.Id}';
    bo.Put_Trucks_on_48_Hour_Hold__c = true;
    var result = sforce.connection.update([bo]);
    if(result[0].success) {
        location.reload();
    } else {
        alert(result.message);
    }
}
```

Note: It's been a while since I've used the Toolkit, so the result handling might not be exact. Please check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in this lines of code

```
var bo = new sforce.SObject("Buyer__c");
if(bo.Put_Trucks_on_48_Hour_Hold__c = 'True')
```

You're creating a new record and then checking for the value of a checkbox (which will always be false). You want to query the value from your current record. Something like this

```
var bo = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Put_Trucks_on_48_Hour_Hold__c  from Buyer__c where id ='{!Buyer__c.Id}' limit 1");
```

Check full example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BPbaIAG) with some extra validations you need to do.